# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectTaskRepository'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am doing project on spring boot...but got this error while running the application. It might be the H2 database error. But to resolve the error localhost should run but program terminates before it being deployed..so i could not able to see what is the actual problem.

Error: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectTaskRepository' defined in com.agileintelligence.projectdashboard.repository.ProjectTaskRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.agileintelligence.projectdashboard.domain.projectTask

Table class

```
package com.agileintelligence.projectdashboard.domain;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import javax.persistence.Entity; 
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

@Entity
public class projectTask {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@NotBlank(message = "Summary cannot be empty")
private String summary;
private String acceptanceCriteria;
private String status;

public projectTask() {
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getSummary() {
    return summary;
}

public void setSummary(String summary) {
    this.summary = summary;
}

public String getAcceptanceCriteria() {
    return acceptanceCriteria;
}

public void setAcceptanceCriteria(String acceptanceCriteria) {
    this.acceptanceCriteria = acceptanceCriteria;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
}
```

Controller

```
package com.agileintelligence.projectdashboard.web;

import com.agileintelligence.projectdashboard.domain.projectTask;
import com.agileintelligence.projectdashboard.service.ProjectTaskService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/board")
@CrossOrigin
public class ProjectTaskController {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectTaskService service;

    @PostMapping("")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addProjectTaskToBoard(@RequestBody projectTask projectTask){

        com.agileintelligence.projectdashboard.domain.projectTask newPT = service.saveOrUpdateProjectTask(projectTask);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newPT, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

Service Class

```
package com.agileintelligence.projectdashboard.service;

import com.agileintelligence.projectdashboard.domain.projectTask;
import com.agileintelligence.projectdashboard.repository.ProjectTaskRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ProjectTaskService {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectTaskRepository projectTaskRepository;

    public projectTask saveOrUpdateProjectTask(projectTask projectTask){

        //In case if status is not set,automatically push it to TO_DO
        if(projectTask.getStatus()==null||projectTask.getStatus().equals("")){
            projectTask.setStatus("TO_DO");
        }
        return projectTaskRepository.save(projectTask);
    }
}
```

Repository

```
package com.agileintelligence.projectdashboard.repository;

import com.agileintelligence.projectdashboard.domain.projectTask;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ProjectTaskRepository extends CrudRepository<projectTask,Long> {

}
```

Comment: Do you have the sequence created in your db?

Comment: I am not able to open the console....because local host is not running. It terminates and eventually.

Comment: Remove @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) and start the app. You are probably missing the sequence required by Hibernate on startup.

Comment: @MladenSavić Removed "@GeneratedValue" and ran the app...but no luck..still shows the same error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong import for the Id here.

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
```

Replace the above one with below from persistence package.

```
import javax.persistence.Id
```

Bonus : Rename your entity with ProjectTask (P uppercase) to prevent future strange issues.

Comment: Thank you it worked. But it is not creating any table in database?

Comment: This ain't my case but facing the same error. Any luck?